# Encoding accented characters using Node.js

Tags: node.js, encoding

I need a simple way to handle this :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.charset = 'utf-8';
    res.end('éàï');
})

app.listen(8080);
```

So far all I get is this when I request :

```
http://localhost:8080/ :

ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

**Edit:** if I change the way I set the charset to this :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    res.end('éàï');
})
```

I actually get this :

```
���
```

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Set the charset to UTF8.

Comment: Have you tried setting the charset with something like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'?

Comment: Yes I did, but same result

Comment: PeterVC's suggesstion should work, IF your script is also stored as UTF-8: in what character set is your script stored?

Comment: Bim! Solved :) The code was encoded in ANSI on my Notepad++. Switching the encoding of my *.js file to 'utf-8' ALONG WITH setting the charset in the header solved the issue. I love this community. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, with the help of **SLaks**, **PeterVC** and **Wrikken**, here is the answer :

Setting the charset in the header  of the response to 'utf-8' is not enough, the *.js file **also** needs to be encoded in 'utf-8'.

Comment: How to "the *.js file also needs to be encoded in 'utf-8'"?